# Faster data structure than unordered_map?

Tags: c++, std

I am looking for a data structure that is faster than C++'s unordered_map in my scenario.

I am storing in the map unsorted unique C-String `char *` (`map.first`) and integers (`map.second`). I can use around 10MB of memory for this data structure. Before I add a new item I need to check if it exists first. So, I am doing a ton of searches and a lot of inserts. The data structure will contain few items ( < 500 ) usually and then it will be deleted. So, I don't need to delete individual items.

I implemented my own AVL self balancing tree (seems to be really good for my case) but it was actually slower compared to `std::unordered_map`.

Do you know any data structure better than unordered_map in my case?

Comment: Can you describe the unique integers?  What is the range?  1 through 500 or are they just random?

Comment: Again, what's the range? Is it any 32 bit value? 64 bit value? 1-1000000? It makes a big difference.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I edited my question.

Comment: @WereAllMadhere: After your edit, your question is completely different now :-)

Comment: if you know the unique C-strings beforehand, you could think about hashing them to an integer in proper range - otherwise the string comparisons will probably dominate any of the mentioned optimisation techniques below

Comment: @Thomas Sparber: I am sorry, I posted a simplified version in the beginning...

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: I don't...

Comment: So your key is a `char *` and *not* an integer? Yes, that changes things completely. I take it you really want a string as the key, rather than a pointer address.

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere `unordered_map` seems to be doing all the optimisations you need: hashing its keys, and then comparing them by buckets. sounds pretty optimal to me

Comment: I agree with @BeyelerStudios.  Also, with an unordered_map you can just do an insert w/o checking if the value exists.  It won't insert if the value exists. The return value will tell you if the insert occurred.

Comment: What kind of keys will it have? Short strings? Regular strings?

Comment: Why an un-ordered map if you need to search it?  The `std::map` is optimized for searching.  You use the `insert`  method to add a key, value pair.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `map` and `unordered_map` are *both* optimized for searching for an exact match on the key, and are totally unoptimized for searching on the value. I worry though if `char *` is really the key, since it will use the pointer address instead of the string value and not be giving the expected results.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I have written my own comparison function, so it compares strings.

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere for `unordered_map` you need both a comparison function and a hash function. Without a custom hash function, the comparison won't even be called on the correct strings.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Yes, I know. Do you have an easy solution to increase the performance in my case? I tried boost::unordered_map but saw no difference...

Comment: You could optimize the hash function by not using all the characters of the string, as long as the resulting hashes are still mostly unique. How long are your strings?

Comment: More or less 10 chars each

Answer (score 4):

A good answer to this would be a combination of linear lookup and binary search.

Basically have a sorted vector of items which you can binary search in. This will have fantastic cache locality and will probably be quicker for the kind of sizes you're looking at. If you need to insert just push it onto a seperate unsorted vector. When you next need to search both do a linear search of the unsorted vector and a binary search of the sorted vector. When your unsorted vector gets big enough (say 10 but profiling will help here) then insert them to the back of the sorted vector and resort it then clear out the 'unsorted' vector.

This doesn't have the best complexity guarantees, but will likely be faster on modern hardware for the kind of sizes you're looking at (linear memory access are FAST and likely beat trees/lists until you get quite large).

Sorting the unsorted vector and then merging it into the sorted one would give a bit of a speed increase at the cost of complexity of code.

Comment: @complexity: use a swap-space and std::merge

Answer (score 3):

If Memory really doesn't matter you can create a huge `vector<bool>` and store if the given value was inserted in your AVL tree.

e.g. have a look at [Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). You could implement it like this.

Comment: No wait... When I say not an issue I mean +/- 10MB's (for 500 items), not GB's of memory.

Comment: Well, it depends on your Maximum number you want to insert... If you know the Limit then it could work out without needing too much memory

Comment: BTW: a `vector<bool>` is implemented to use bits to store the individual fields. So I bet it won't need to much memory!

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere a `vector<bool>` that could hold all the integers from 0 to 2^31 would take 268 MB. Allocating that much memory and clearing it each time is bound to be slow, so I'm not sure this solution works out.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your use case calls for a set rather than a map. Do you really need a map for some reason not clear in the question? If not, an `unordered_set` would be a better choice and if you are dealing with a small enough range a `vector<bool>` as suggested by Thomas Sparber.